# Could not identify shiboken version (5.15.2)

Tags: shiboken2

I try use combination from shiboken + C++ + Qt on Windows as my colleagues and it is not working

Console: x86 from MVS with administrator,  QT 5.15.2 , CMAKE 3.19.8

Python from MVS installer 3.7 (use paths: PYTHONHOME C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64, path : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64)

Shiboken download from https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/

```
cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug 
C:\Users\...qt-5.15.2\pyside-setup\sources\shiboken2\ -DBUILD_TESTS=False 
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH='C:\Users\...\qt-5.15.2;' -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX='C:\Users\...\QT\shiboken2-debug' -
DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE='C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\MicrosoftVisualStudio\Shared\Python37_64\python_d.exe'
```

OUTPUT:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:51 (message):
  Could not identify shiboken version.  Error:
```

when i change cmake file i saw interesting: PYTHON_DEBUG_LIBRARIES is empty

Having examined the cmakefile, I can saw that wherever the cmake calls the execute_process with python_d, python does not work and returns null, path to python_d is correct. I have python_d.exe in directory. I try install python not from MVS, and have same result. I try use 3.9 python. I cleaned sys paths from old python versions.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks colleague, it was a bad path DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE, i add message in Cmake file to output correct path, and successed used.
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python37_64/python_d.exe"

Before that I reinstalled the MVS, but I don’t think it had any effect